# How to send all the messages under a contact to an email

Tags: iphone

I need to send all my messages under a contacts name to an email. Is there a way to select all and then send to a given email?

Answer (score 1):

You can only hold one text bubble, then select what text you want and forward it via sms/imessage again, or you can just copy the text and then compose a new email and paste the text in there. :)